# Cannot install JavaFX app on Android x86_64

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, javafxports

I managed to build a JavaFX app using gradle and javafxport but the apk fail to install on my device.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'java.Main'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = ['java.**.*']
    }
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.superflush.java'
    androidSdk = 'C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk'
    }
}
```

<del>My device is a Asus Zenfone2 running stock Android 5.0</del>

<del>It is a x86_64 so I suspect that might be an issue but im not sure how to diagnose. Any suggestion how to solve this problem?</del>

I managed to get my hands on standard 4.4.2 ARM phone so it installs but it wont run (blackscreen) and here is the logcat error output at execution:

```
E/DalvikLauncher(12088): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "application.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.superflu
sh.java-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.superflush.java-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.resolveApplicationClass(DalvikLauncher.java:232)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher.launchApp(DalvikLauncher.java:134)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.getLauncherAndLaunchApplication(FXDalvikEntity.java:118)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at javafxports.android.FXDalvikEntity.surfaceCreated(FXDalvikEntity.java:144)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
E/DalvikLauncher(12088):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my project structure, Main.java being the main:

[image: Project structure in Eclipse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, under `mainClassName` you should add the name of you main class (let say `JavaFXApp`), including the package. something like this:

```
mainClassName = 'com.superflush.java.JavaFXApp'
```

Inside `android`, you don't need the `applicationPackage` line.

Once you have successfully built your apk, if you install it on your device, try to run it. Keep it connected, and run `adb logcat` on the command line to see all the output and find any possible exception, if it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Based on the last changes on the OP answer, this is a more proper answer.

For starters, the Main java class should be inside a package properly named. You must follow Android package name convention rules, so something like this will work:

```
package com.julioqc.superflush;
```

Also note, you will find your main class under these folders:

```
src/main/java/com/julioqc/superFlush/Main.java
```

(Note `main/java` is not part of the name of the package).

Accordingly, you should have your resources under the same structure of folders:

```
src/main/resources/com/julioqc/superFlush/application.css
src/main/resources/com/julioqc/superFlush/Image.jpg ...
```

Finally, this should be the **Build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'com.julioqc.superflush.Main'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = ['com.julioqc.superflush.**.*']
    }
    android {
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk'
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! It tried logcat waiting while waiting for a reply and did find an issue with what you say!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "application.Main"
How would I figure out what goes in "mainClassName" exactly?? Thats what I dont seem to understand :(

Comment: Did you change `mainClassName`?

Comment: i tried many things... I dont know what it is supposed to be like and thats the problem. The java project main class is located "\src\application\Main.java". Would that mean anything?

Comment: For starters, try to post your project structure (packages and classes), including the main class.

Comment: It seems `application.Main` should be your `mainClassName`. Check the name of the package on Main.java.

Comment: I did so and still same error in logcat. I can only suspect the build being done wrong :(

Comment: Let's check other possible issue: are you using gradle 2.4? I'm not sure if that will work. I'm using 2.2.1 for instance. Comment the first three lines of your build.gradle file and check again. Also post your output from running `gradlew androidInstall`.

Comment: install works, version 2.2.1 returns same results. I found out that the main class has to be under `main\java\superflush` to be built. I'll redo a refactor of the project and try again.

Comment: *sigh* same error in logcat after refactor of project... I think i'll just give up at this point

Comment: Let me help you with this, if you want to share your project, send me a link with it, so I can have a look at your main class. It's okay if you can't share it.

Comment: I sent you an invite in bitbucket to my repo.

Comment: Ok, where's the build.gradle file?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some changes you should make. I've also build the apk with some few more changes on your code (minor things). Let me know how do I send you the code

Comment: Sir! You will make my day :D
I'll give you write access in the repo if you wanna commit your changes and i'll try them

Answer (score 1):

> It is a x86_64 so I suspect that might be an issue but im not sure how
>   to diagnose.

To diagnose why an app is not installing, execute an install using the adb via the command prompt

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

You will get output indicating if the install on the device has failed with a reason for the failure.

If your app is installing correctly on ARM devices but not x86 devices then it is likely your adb is not shipping all the required native libraries. If this is the case then the adb install command will return the error `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`