# Android javafxports NullPointerException

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I'm getting a force close crash on a small Android app I made for school using Javafxports.

[Here is the code and APKs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4dopsx0fvw1bwz/gti350-lab-4.rar?dl=0)

And the logcat returns this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474): Process: com.julioqc.superflush, PID: 4474  
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleWindowManager$1.run(MonocleWindowManager.java:179)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$155(PlatformImpl.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$156(PlatformImpl.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4474):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
I/cm.log.servpro( 1334): [Privacy]/ com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox is not in contact list
W/ActivityManager(  726):   Force finishing activity com.julioqc.superflush/javafxports.android.FXActivity
```

What is causing this error in my code??

EDIT: found out the issue is caused by some unsupported JavaFX 8 dialogs. Trying alternative.

Comment: As we already [discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31235542/3956070), the packages name can't start with `main.java.`. One I've changed them in your project, I've also needed to set the origin of resurces to `/com/julioqc/...`. Once I had it running on my desktop I created the apk, and installed without problems. Anyway, you are using JavaFX 8 features not yet supported by JavaFXPorts, like `Dialogs`.

Comment: Folder hierarchy has been respected as you showed me previously. So it will install but just crashes at launch for some obscur reason.

Comment: I've used your last version at the repo, not the link you have provided. Are these different versions?

Comment: yes and no, the repo will have the main.java. to make it run under Eclipse but it is manually removed afterwards when using gradlew. The verison stripped from all the main.java. is in the link. I think its a font issue but they havent changed so i'm confused.

Comment: I'll check your link later, but as I said you need to set the resources path too, and get rid of JavaFX Dialogs.

Comment: where can I find what is and what isnt compatible with the plugin?

Comment: From Java 8 you can use Lambdas because of the Retrolambdas project, but not Streams nor Dialogs. APIs like Media or Printing are also not supported yet. While you can build the apk, those will fail on runtime, so you have to check the output logcat regularly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Got it running but yes, app will crash on dialog prompt and dropdown menus...

Comment: If you want to use dialogs, have a look at [Gluon Charm](http://gluonhq.com/products/charm/). It also includes a way to deal with views. Check this [sample](https://github.com/jperedadnr/HelloCharm).

Comment: nice stuff. Still getting crash from it however... ill just update link with latest code if you want to check